# Please help me to Factorize the V's in terms of Z's

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that   $$V_1Z_1 =V_2 Z_2 +V_3 Z_3, $$

express $V_1/( V_2 + V_3)$  in terms of $Z_1, Z_2, Z_3$ only.
The V's should be at the left hand side. while the Z's at the right hand side.
Please the question is not from any topic in pre-calculus or algebra but instead I am trying to prove something with it.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189)
Yash Jain has tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing
[$\rm \LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).  **Why rollback**?  Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Btw, this question assumed that $V1/(V2+V3)$ can be determined by $Z1, Z2, Z3$---but this is *wrong*: take $V1 = 13, V2 = 12, V3 = 5$.  \begin{align}
V1 = Z1, V2 = Z2, V3 = Z3 &\implies V1^2 = V2 ^2 + V3^2 \quad\text{(true)} \\ &\implies \frac{V1}{ V2 + V3} = \frac{13}{17} \\
V1' = \frac{120}{13}, V2' = Z3, V3' = Z2&\implies \frac{120}{13} Z1 = Z2 \cdot Z3 + Z3 \cdot Z2 \quad\text{(true)} \\ &\implies \frac{V1'}{ V2' + V3'} = \frac{120/13}{5 +12} = \frac{120}{221} 
\end{align}
Therefore, $V1/(V2+V3)$ is *not* determined by $Z1,Z2,Z3$, so we can't write the former in terms of $Z1,Z2,Z3$.